# Coolant smell outside of car

Tags: cooling-system

I have a 2010 Nissan Murano. Last summer (2018) I started smelling coolant when I get out of the vehicle or am at a drive thru with my window down. There is never any coolant on my garage floor. The coolant level has never gone down. I took it to Nissan when I received a notice for a free inspection.  They said it is the head gasket and that the leak is so tiny that they recommend to just "monitor" it.  They also quoted $4,000.00 to repair it. I took it to a mechanic that we have used for years and totally trust.  He said he cannot find anything wrong with it.  He also said they could not even smell a coolant odor.  Not sure what to do at this point.  It is my understanding that if you EVER smell coolant, there is a problem.  Both places did pressure checks as well. Any recommendations?

Comment: I assume that by "pressure check", you mean a compression check. Theoretically that should show you whether or not it has a blow head gasket, but in practice the compression might not produce quite high enough of pressures to reproduce combustion conditions.

$4000 sounds pretty high. I'd recommend asking around for multiple quotes.

You should look at your oil to see if there's water in it. If there isn't, then the gasket break is between a coolant holes and the cylinder. If it's a bad leak, it should have white coolant-smelling exhaust, but if it's minor you won't.

Comment: Does the car overheat?

Comment: Test kits are available to cheaply detect the presence of exhaust gases in coolant; has one of these been tried? Anecdotally, the car I've had for the past 10 years has frequently smelled of coolant after I park it up after a good thrash; level never drops and I've never had any problems with the engine in this regard. I'm not sure I'd adopt "if you EVER smell coolant" as a rule